# How to remove all ip in a text file with Notepad++

Tags: text, ssh, ip, notepad++

I have a large text file containing words like this:

```
12.0.84.130|test|test|United States (US)
12.0.84.131
12.0.84.132
```

So i wanted to remove all the IP from that text file and make them appear like this:

```
12.0.84.130|test|test|United States (US)
```

How can i do this in Notepad++?

Comment: I can't even understand what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: Do you want to remove lines that contain a single IP address and nothing else?

Comment: @Mikkel & Toto just read here Mohit answer and comments you will understand!

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: your answer is yeah i want to remove just ip address which is in single line and if ip contains words like `12.0.84.130|test|test|United States (US)` then it should not be remove!

Comment: @VickyMalhotra: This could be done only if lines are ordered. But a better approch will be a script.

Comment: it's fixed bro i'm looking answer for this problem- https://superuser.com/questions/1242784/how-to-remove-specific-duplicate-line-in-notepad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to delete lines that contain only an IP address, here is how I'd do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?:\R|$)`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
\d+         : 1 or more digits
(?:         : start non capture group
  \.        : a dot
  \d+       : 1 or more digits
){3}        : end group, repeated 3 times
\R|$        : any kind of line break or end of line
```

If you want more accurate match for an iIP address, change `\d+` by `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?1)){3}` where `(?1)` is the same regex that the one in group 1.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?1)){3}(?:\R|$)`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Hey @Toto it's working fine as i expected but not working for some ip example here https://i.imgur.com/3UlvKJ6.png

Comment: Replace the `\R` by `(?:\R|$)` line break or end of line. See my edit

Comment: Have any idea about this ?https://superuser.com/questions/1242784/how-to-remove-specific-duplicate-line-in-notepad

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the following works best to match and replace an exact IP address:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

If you only want to remove IP's that contain new lines after them (Exactly like your before and after in the question) use:

`(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)([\r\n]+)`

(Keep in mind when testing with your example 12.0.84.132 was left over because there is no newline after 12.0.84.132 when copying and pasting)

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex in Notepad++
Replace and search by 
Find what: (^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$)
Replace: \1 |test|test|United States (US)

Dont forget to check Regular Expression in Notepad++ :)