# How to find separated words in notepad++

Tags: text, notepad++

I have a text file which contains word like this

```
137.147.138.224|write|write|Australia
137.154.4.3|United States
```

And I want to find

```
137.154.4.3|United States
```

There may be anything in place of `137.154.4.3|United States` like `155.186.7.9|India` , `185.173.4.7|Japan`So i have long list of words like that and i just wanted to find the words contains only one vertical bar |

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all ip in a text file with Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775605/how-to-remove-all-ip-in-a-text-file-with-notepad)

Comment: Nopes that's for ip it's only for ip but with | word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the lines which have an IP, a `|` and then a country, you can use this regex pattern:

`\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\|[^|]+$`

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+  # digits (1 or more) and dots
\|                  # string literal
[^|]+               # 1 or more characters that are not '|'
$                   # end of line
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kD3pqO/1)